# partial templates loading customization via custom sfView child

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have sf1.4 setup with my own custom sfPHPView and sfPartialView classes which does some extra things about loading template files in case of missing templates (falling back to default templates ...)

I have it activated via this view Classes definition:

APP_ROOT/config/module.yml

```
all:
  enabled:                  true
  view_class:               MyProjectName
  partial_view_class:       MyProjectName
```

**Problem**

Everythings is fine untill I try to load partial from other module.

In that case `sfConfig::get()` returns only values loaded for current action module, so PartialHelper and its get_partial() cannot find my wanted view classes.

To be concrete it tryes to find that config variable in `mod_partialmodulename_partial_view_class`, but it has loaded only action module configs.

Does exists some common recipe which allows to have these "other module" configs loaded too?

Comment: Your `view_class` & `partial_view_class` are always different for each module?

Comment: Because i have it set in global /config dir, its the same for each module, but the config_handler of module.yml loads always only the current. When i print_r(sfConfig::getAll()) i see only mod_currentmodulename_* vars. So PartialHelper then uses the default when i want to include partial from other module.

Comment: i solved it by customization of PartialHelper so it checks mod_currentmodulename_partial_view_class if there is nothing set in mod_partialmodulename_partial_view_class, but its a mess. I tryed to change module.yml config_handler to load each modules settings, but after that some others sf core behaviour started to be buggy, so i stopped playing with that.